# In Robinson Crusoe, once you build the brick, what happens to it?

Tags: robinson-crusoe

As I understand it, the brick increases the palisade level by 1 when it is built. Then what? Do you discard the brick? Turn it over and can build it again? Get a permanent +1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As I understand it, the brick increases the palisade level by 1 when it is built. Then what?

It is placed in the invention spaces.

[Rules](https://s3.amazonaws.com/geekdo-files.com/bgg173697?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D%22robinson_crusoe_rulebook_EN_net.pdf%22&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJYFNCT7FKCE4O6TA%2F20210517%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210517T121011Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=120&X-Amz-Signature=dbe8c79409000106fc699e5ef891e4db6071dfa5a0545ac0b6416203ba568931), p. 18:

> At the end of the Action Phase, any Inventions in the Future Resources space will
> trigger their effect, be flipped to the Item side and then placed in the Invention
> spaces on the board (even personal Inventions).

It is not turned over to be built again on its own, but if some effect turns it over, then it

1. undoes its effect (you lose 1 palisade level)
2. Can be built again.

Rules, p. 18:

> The Brick increases the Palisade level by 1. If, later in the game, it is flipped
> to the Invention side, the Palisade level must be reduced by 1. If this is not
> possible, nothing happens.

Rules, p. 18:

> During the game, an effect may force players to flip Items back to their Invention
> side. From the start of the following round, such an Item ceases to be available
> (it is still available for the current round). It must be built again before it can be
> used.

Comment: Thanks! So what happens if animals attack and reduce the palisade by 1? Say I have the brick and that makes my palisade level 1, then animals attack to reduce it by 1. Do I lose the brick? Am I fully protected?

Comment: When the animals reduce the level by 1, move the marker down one. Leave the Brick alone. If you later lose (flip) the brick, then reduce the palisade marker by one.